# why I need put *.so files in both armeabi-v7a and armeabi folders?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have to use a .so lib file by others, and it is necessary put the same file in both folders. Otherwise installing can NOT guarantee the lib file be placed in /data/data//lib.
why ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not the same. `armeabi-v7a` is optimized for v7a version which has float point operation support. With `armeabi-v7a` as the target device, it will run faster than `armeabi` which doesn't provide float point operation support. It's okay if you let your librariese on in `armeabi`, but if you can't take the advantage of the target CPU if your app is run on `armeabi-v7a` platform.

Have the different separated directory for your native library will let your app more portable, you should provide `x86`,`x86_64`,`mips`, etc. if you want your app run on any Android device or emulator currently supported.