# Android with armeabi AND armeabi-v7a dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, java-native-interface, dependency-management

I have an app A with dependencies B and C.  B has native libraries for both armeabi and armeabi-v7a.  C only has native libraries for armeabi.  The app fails to run on an armeabi-v7a device.  (`UnsatisfiedLinkError`.)  If I run an app depending only on B or only on C, it works fine.  As near as I understand, the phone looks for armeabi-v7a libraries, and if it finds any (e.g. B), it stops looking, and so does not find any C libraries.  If it does not find any v7a libraries, it continues on and finds the armeabi libraries.  Is there a way to tell Gradle to hide B's armeabi-v7a libraries, or promote C's armeabi libraries?  Or to tell it to copy the eventual armeabi folder into armeabi-v7a, or something?

I've seen [a number of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065940/android-ndk-armeabi-vs-armeabi-v7a-folder), but they seem to deal with manually-included libraries, or don't really have a clear solution.

Surely I'm not expected to repackage my dependencies by hand, just because one of them includes an extra architecture?

Comment: _"Is there a way to tell Gradle to hide B's armeabi-v7a libraries"_. The normal way of doing this would be to specify an `abiFilters` that only includes `armeabi`. But I don't know if the Android Gradle plugin even recognizes `armeabi` as a valid ABI anymore, since it was deprecated long ago. You may be able to use `packagingOptions { exclude` to exclude the `armeabi-v7a` library from the APK/AAB.

Comment: Note that you probably won't be able to publish your app on Google Play if it only includes armeabi libraries, since there's a 64-bit requirement nowadays.

Comment: @Michael Oh, whaddayaknow, it worked!  Thanks!  If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it.